# Windows Phone Calendar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application I need to add some dates in system calendar. Is it possible and how can I implement this?

Comment: Can you give an example of date that you want to add ?

Comment: I want to add some important date

Comment: Do you want to add date or add an entry to calendar?

Answer (score 3):

In Mango, which is the current version, you only have [read-only access to the calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286421%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), so you won't be able to add to it directly.

What you could try, which may or may not be suitable for your project, is to use the Live SDK to [write to the user's Hotmail calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx). If the same Live account is being used in their Calendars section, your appointment would show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use 3d party tools as telerik to your application which has the ui for windows phone 7 and then use their custom controls.
http://www.telerik.com/